# How to render the checkbox in editor window with corresponding boolean value(i.e)checked or unchecked in MVC 4..?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine

Model:
    public partial class TBLAppUser
    {
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
    }

View:
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(u => u.useredit.isActive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you initialize an instance of `TBLAppUser`, set the `IsActive` of that instance to `true`, and pass that instance to the `view`. This is quite a simple situation. I think you better look at introductory tutorials found in here asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started .

following is how your controller action would look like

```
[HttpGet] 
public ActionResult Index()
{ 
    var mainModel = //what ever the model you represent by u in the view
    mainModel.useredit = new TBLAppUser{ isActive = true}; 
    return View(mainModel); 
}
```